# boost::asio async_read_some works once then stops working, why? (uses shared_ptr)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have been trying to start from http://think-async.com/asio/boost_asio_1_3_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server/connection.cpp and modify it to my needs.  I want to accept multiple clients one after another and eventually read data over TCP.  My server works fine if I run it and then in another shell use

```
nc localhost 3731
```

then hit control-C.  The first client is properly disconnected. I then enter the same command again.  The trouble comes on the next client; it accepts and prints out the start of reading fine but then when I hit control-C on the second client it does not seem to get the disconnect message. I can't figure out why.  Any help with boost::asio async_read_some?

Here's the output debug messages showing the first client working then successive clients not being disconnected properly:

```
./a.out                                                          
Made connection       at address 80x2240370
Added connection to ConnectionManager at 80x2240370
  Starting read at address 80x2240370
Made connection       at address 80x22449f0
Did read of 0 with error code asio.misc:2
Accepting bytes.
Removing connection to ConnectionManager at 80x2240370
Destroying connection at address 80x2240370
Added connection to ConnectionManager at 80x22449f0
  Starting read at address 80x22449f0
Made connection       at address 80x2248af0
```

Here's the full source code edited for brevity but still showing the problem:

```
// compile with: g++ asiohelp.cpp -lboost_system -lpthread  -std=c++11

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#define CONTROL_PORT "3731"
#define CONTROL_BIND_ADDRESS "127.0.0.1"

namespace hsd {
namespace net {

class HSDConnectionManager;

class HSDConnection: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<HSDConnection> {
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
  boost::array<char, 16384> readBuffer_;
  HSDConnectionManager& connectionManager_;
public:
  explicit HSDConnection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
      HSDConnectionManager& manager);
  ~HSDConnection(void);

  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket(void);

  /// Start the first asynchronous operation for the connection.
  void startRead(void);
  void handleRead(const boost::system::error_code& e,
      std::size_t bytesTransferred);
  void stop(void);
private:
  void continueRead(void);

};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<HSDConnection> ConnectionPtr;
}
}


namespace hsd {
namespace net {

class HSDConnectionManager: private boost::noncopyable {
public:
  void start(ConnectionPtr c);

  void stop(ConnectionPtr c);

  void stop_all();

private:
  std::set<ConnectionPtr> connections_;
};

}
}

namespace hsd {
namespace net {

class ControlServer {
public:
  // Construct the server to listen on the specified TCP address and port
  explicit ControlServer(boost::asio::io_service& io_service_,
      const std::string& address, const std::string& port);
  virtual ~ControlServer(void);
  // Run the server's io_service loop.
  void run();

  // Stop the server.
  void stop();

  // Handle packet
  virtual void packetReceived(std::string result);

private:
  /// Handle completion of an asynchronous accept operation.
  void handleAccept(const boost::system::error_code& e);

  /// Handle a request to stop the server.
  void handleStop();

  /// The io_service used to perform asynchronous operations.
  boost::asio::io_service io_service_;

  /// Acceptor used to listen for incoming connections.
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

  /// The connection manager which owns all live connections.
  HSDConnectionManager connectionManager_;

  /// The next connection to be accepted.
  ConnectionPtr nextConnection_;

};

}

}


using namespace std;
using namespace boost::system::errc;

namespace hsd {
namespace net {

ControlServer::ControlServer(boost::asio::io_service& io_service_,
    const std::string& address, const std::string& port) :
    io_service_(), acceptor_(io_service_), connectionManager_(), nextConnection_() {
  nextConnection_ = ConnectionPtr(
      new HSDConnection(io_service_, connectionManager_));
  // Open the acceptor with the option to reuse the address (i.e. SO_REUSEADDR).
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service_);
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(address, port);
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);
  acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol());
  acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
  acceptor_.bind(endpoint);
  acceptor_.listen();

  acceptor_.async_accept(nextConnection_->socket(),
      boost::bind(&ControlServer::handleAccept, this,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));

}

ControlServer::~ControlServer(void) {
  cout << "Destroying ControlServer\n";
}

void ControlServer::handleAccept(const boost::system::error_code& e) {
  if (e == success) {
    connectionManager_.start(nextConnection_);
    nextConnection_.reset(
        new HSDConnection(io_service_, connectionManager_));
    //nextConnection_ = ConnectionPtr(new HSDConnection(io_service_,
    //             connectionManager_, *hsPacketReaderListener_s));
    acceptor_.async_accept(nextConnection_->socket(),
        boost::bind(&ControlServer::handleAccept, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }
}

void ControlServer::packetReceived(std::string result) {
  cout << "Got packet: " << result << "\n";

}

}
}


using namespace std;

namespace hsd {
namespace net {
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& HSDConnection::socket(void) {
  return socket_;
}

HSDConnection::HSDConnection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
    HSDConnectionManager& manager) :
    socket_(io_service), connectionManager_(manager), readBuffer_()

{
  cout << "Made connection       at address " << ios::hex << this << "\n";
}

HSDConnection::~HSDConnection(void) {
  cout << "Destroying connection at address " << ios::hex << this << "\n";
}

void HSDConnection::handleRead(const boost::system::error_code& e,
    std::size_t bytesTransferred) {
  cout << "Did read of " << bytesTransferred << " with error code " << e
      << "\n";
  std::string byteString(readBuffer_.data(), bytesTransferred);
  vector<string> result;
  cout << "Accepting bytes.\n";
  //hsPacketCore_.acceptBytes(byteString, result);
  for (string &packet : result) {
    //listener_->packetReceived(packet);
  }
  if (e == boost::system::errc::success
      || e == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
    continueRead();
  } else if (bytesTransferred == 0) {
    connectionManager_.stop(shared_from_this());
  }
}

void HSDConnection::continueRead(void) {
  cout << "Continuing read at address " << ios::hex << this << "\n";
  socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(readBuffer_),
      boost::bind(&HSDConnection::handleRead, shared_from_this(),
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void HSDConnection::startRead(void) {
  cout << "  Starting read at address " << ios::hex << this << "\n";

  socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(readBuffer_),
      boost::bind(&HSDConnection::handleRead, shared_from_this(),
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void HSDConnection::stop(void) {
  socket_.close();
}
}
}

namespace hsd {
namespace net {

void HSDConnectionManager::start(ConnectionPtr c) {
  connections_.insert(c);
  std::cout << "Added connection to ConnectionManager at " << std::ios::hex << c
      << "\n";
  c->startRead();
}

void HSDConnectionManager::stop(ConnectionPtr c) {
  std::cout << "Removing connection to ConnectionManager at " << std::ios::hex
      << c << "\n";
  connections_.erase(c);
  c->stop();
}
}
}


using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace std;
using namespace hsd::net;

int main()
{

  try
  {
    // We need to create a server object to accept incoming client connections.
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    // The io_service object provides I/O services, such as sockets,
    // that the server object will use.
    ControlServer server(io_service, CONTROL_BIND_ADDRESS, CONTROL_PORT);

    // Run the io_service object to perform asynchronous operations.
    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two instances of io_service. The difference in behaviour is from the fact that you call async_accept on sockets initialised from two different io_service instances. The confusion comes from the way that you named the parameter io_service_ the same as the member variable. I managed to fix your code by making the member variable a reference.

```
    /// The io_service used to perform asynchronous operations.
    boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
```

and then disambiguate the variable in the formal parameters of the constructor, and initialise the member variable with this parameter.

```
    ControlServer::ControlServer(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, 
        const std::string& address, const std::string& port) :
        io_service_(io_service), acceptor_(io_service),
        connectionManager_(), nextConnection_() {
```

Another option is to expose the io_service member variable and then run that io_service.

```
    // The io_service object provides I/O services, such as sockets,
    // that the server object will use.
    ControlServer server(CONTROL_BIND_ADDRESS, CONTROL_PORT);
    
    // Run the io_service object to perform asynchronous operations.
    server.io_service().run();
```

I hope that makes sense, I only used boost::asio for the first time last week, doing a writeup of something similar.

Comment: I enjoyed the blog read.  With regards to the blog entry, one common idiom for Asio is to use `enable_shared_from_this` to allow an object to extend its own life in an asynchronous call chain.  See the official tutorial's [asynchronous TCP daytime server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html) for an example.

Comment: Thanks! I discovered shared_from_this() a few days ago and have been experimenting with it too, it's a really good feature, and I'm planning on including it in my next write up. In the past I'd avoided using various designs because I couldn't get a shared_ptr from inside the class scope, and can use them now. I've also started using boost::bind instead of the raw lambdas, and you end up with cleaner code and a bit less of it that way too :-)